# Check if a column has an value if so right true or false to column next to it

Tags: r, parameters

i was wondering how to make something that checks if column Lair in the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cemo1b8mzgfhria/japansegment%20data.csv)

is below or above an certain threshold lets say below 0.5 is called LOH en
above is called imbalance. So the calls LOH and INBALANCE should be written in a new column. I tried something as the code below.

```
detection<-function(assay,method,thres){
  if(method=="threshold"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]<1.1000000 & segmenten["intensity"]>0.900000 & segmenten["Lair"]>thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  if(method=="cnloh"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]<1.1000000 & segmenten["intensity"]>0.900000 & segmenten["Lair"]<thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  if(method=="gain"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]>1.1000000 & segmenten["Lair"]<thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  if(method=="loss"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]<0.900000 & segmenten["Lair"]<thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  if(method=="bloss"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]<0.900000 & segmenten["Lair"]>thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  if(method=="bgain"){
    idx<-ifelse(segmenten["intensity"]>1.100000 & segmenten["Lair"]>thres,TRUE,FALSE)
  }
  return(idx)
}
```

After this part the next step is to write the data from the function to the existing table.
Anyone has an idea

Comment: No need to define a function for it. Just use `factor(intensity > thres, levels=c(FALSE, TRUE), labels=c("LOH", "IMBALANCE"))`.

Comment: @Backlin thanks! 1 question left how does the threshold behave and is it possible to give the scoring 3 parameters like LOH,BALANCE and IMBALANCE

Comment: `factor(findInterval(intensity, thres), levels=0:2, labels=c(...))` where `thres` are the two cutoff points separating the groups. The way you set out to solve this suggests that you should read up on the basics of R though. There are many good books to chose from, and since you seem to know how to program I'd suggest [the art of R programming](http://nostarch.com/artofr.htm). It briefly covers the basics (without unnecessary fluff) before moving on to more advanced topics. I found it very useful.

Comment: @backlin sorry for the last comment i read yours to fast.  And the book is an good option indeed thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your desired result is not clear enough I made some assumptions and wrote something that might be useful or not.

First at all, inside your function there is an object segmenten which is not defined, I suppose this is the data set supplied as an input, then you used ifelse and the returning results are `TRUE` or `FALSE` but you want either `LOH` or `INBALANCE` when some conditions are met.

You want `INBALANCE` when `... & segmenten["Lair"]>thres` and `LOH` otherwise (here `...` means the other part of the condition) this will give a vector, but you want it in the main dataset as an addional column, don't you? So maybe this could be a new starting point for you to improve your code.

```
detection <- function(assay, method=c('threshold', 'cnloh', 'gain', 'loss', 'bloss', 'bgain'),
                    thres=0.5){
  x <- assay
  idx <- switch(match.arg(method),
         threshold = ifelse(x["intensity"]<1.1 & x["intensity"]>0.9 & x["Lair"]>thres, 'INBALANCE', 'LOH'),
         cnloh     = ifelse(x["intensity"]<1.1 & x["intensity"]>0.9 & x["Lair"]<thres, 'LOH', 'INBALANCE'),
         gain      = ifelse(x["intensity"]>1.1 & x["Lair"]<thres, 'LOH', 'INBALANCE'),
         loss      = ifelse(x["intensity"]<0.9 & x["Lair"]<thres,'LOH', 'INBALANCE'),
         bloss     = ifelse(x["intensity"]<0.9 & x["Lair"]>thres, 'INBALANCE', 'LOH'),
         bgain     = ifelse(x["intensity"]>1.1 & x["Lair"]>thres, 'INBALANCE', 'LOH'))

  colnames(idx) <- 'Checking'
  return(cbind(x, as.data.frame(idx)))
  }
```

Example:

```
Data <- read.csv("japansegment data.csv", header=T)

result <- detection(Data, method='threshold', thres=0.5) # 'threshold' is the default value for method
head(result)
       SNP_NAME x0 x1 y pos.start   pos.end chrom count copynumber intensity allele.B   Lair uncertain sample_id
1 SNP_A-1656705  0  0 0    836727  27933161     1   230          2    1.0783        1 0.9218     FALSE GSM288035
2 SNP_A-1677548  0  0 0  28244579 246860994     1  4408          2    0.9827        1 0.9236     FALSE GSM288035
3 SNP_A-1669537  0  0 0    100819 159783145     2  3480          2    0.9806        1 0.9193     FALSE GSM288035
4 SNP_A-1758569  0  0 0 159783255 159791136     2     5          2    1.7244        1 0.9665     FALSE GSM288035
5 SNP_A-1662168  0  0 0 159817465 168664268     2   250          2    0.9786        1 0.9197     FALSE GSM288035
6 SNP_A-1723506  0  0 0 168721411 168721920     2     2          2    1.8027       -4     NA     FALSE GSM288035
   Checking
1 INBALANCE
2 INBALANCE
3 INBALANCE
4       LOH
5 INBALANCE
6       LOH
```

Using `match.arg` and `switch` functions will help you to avoid a lot of `if` statements.